# How can I merge two files where there is a slight variation in the values of columns 2 and 3?

Tags: perl, awk

I want to merger two files with slight variation in the values of columns 2, and 3. If the name is same in both files, and the difference in the values of column 2 or 3 is five  (e.g. with difference is 5 relative to file 1, 500-495, 600-605 in column 2,3), print the column 1,2,3 from file 1 and column 4th from file 2. If columns of file2 do not match with file 1 or vice versa then print the values of file2. My command is not working. I would appreciate if you could kindly help in my code. Thanks

`$ awk 'NR==FNR {key[$1,$2,$3]=$0; next}{if (($1,$2,$3) in key) print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file1 file2`

#### file 1

```
Name1 100 200 K
Name2 300 400 K
Name3 500 600 K
Name7 200 300 K
```

#### file2

```
Name1 100 200 L
Name2 300 400 L
Name3 495 605 L
Name4 600 900 L
```

#### Output

```
Name1 100 200 K,L
Name2 300 400 K,L
Name3 500 600 K,L
Name4 600 900 L
Name7 200 300 K
```

Comment: Not enough information. Explain HOW it's not working.  Notice that nothing in your awk code says anything about differences being 5 (do you mean <= 5)?  Is the OUTPUT section in your post the desired output or actual output?

Comment: Thanks for your response. OUTPUT file is my desired output. The difference of 5 means upto less than 5 or upto more than 5.  If the file 1 has range 500 600, then 495-505 for 500 and 595-605 for 600.

Comment: A more clear way of saying that would be "a maximum difference of 5". You should edit your question to add in the details from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
function abs(x) { return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) }    
!seen[$1] {
    seen[$1] = $2 FS $3 FS $4
    next
}
{
    split(seen[$1], a)
    if (abs($2-a[1]) <= 5 && abs($3-a[2] <= 5))
        seen[$1] = seen[$1] "," $4  
}
END {
    for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]
}
```

New names that haven't been seen before are added to the array `seen`. Otherwise, the 2nd and 3rd columns are compared. I have assumed that you meant the different should be five *or less*. You should edit your question to clarify whether that is the case.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f merge.awk file1 file2
Name1 100 200 K,L
Name2 300 400 K,L
Name3 500 600 K,L
Name4 600 900 L
Name7 200 300 K
```